# How to substract a hashed password from database in Python

Tags: python, mysql

In data, coming from `data = cursor.fetchone()`, I have `(id, 'user', 'email', 'pbkdf2:sha256:50000$')` [A user from the db].

How can I do to get the crypted password?
I want to compare it with the entered password and do the login.

I tryed `password = data['user_password']`, but when I ckeck with `app.logger.info(password)` it shows me nothing.

'user_password' is the column from my database. This is why I did `data['user_password']`. Is this wrong?

Help me please! Thank you!

Comment: You say that something is wrong, but as far as I can see you don't say what it is. What is happening that you don't expect?

Comment: app.logger.info(password) shows me nothing. So I suppose that password = data['user_password'] doens't work for me. How could I change that, so I can compare the two passwords?

Comment: I'm not sure but per ```<input type="password" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>``` should not you be using  ```data['inputPassword']```?

Comment: user_password it's the column from the database, since in data I have the user from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to achieve your purpose is to get the `column` value by using its `index`.

```
password = data[3]
app.logger.info(password)
```